# ". . . who probably confounded the word with a familiar oath" - What *is* the "familiar oath"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XVII, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_17)

> Passage 263
>
> ...That Trent, he come first, with his 'and in a bloody rag. I was
> near 'em as I am to you; and I could make out he was all to bits—'eard
> his breath rattle in his blooming lungs as he come down the ladder.
> Yes, they was a scared lot, small blame to 'em, I say! The next after
> Trent, come him as was mate.”
> “Goddedaal!” I exclaimed.
>
> “And a good name for him too,” chuckled the man-o'-war's man, **who probably confounded the word with a familiar oath**. “A good name too;
> only it weren't his. He was a gen'lem'n born, sir, as had gone maskewerading.

With what familiar oath does the speaker confound/confuse the name 'Goddedaal'?

Comment: Or possibly the trisyllabic name Goddedaal was heard as "Go to hell!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Goddedaal" is the mate's name, but it is not an English name.  (The spelling suggests a Scandanavian origin.)  It sounds a bit like "God, damn", a blasphemous oath that I think the author may have preferred not to write explicitly, but to which he did not mind making an allusion.  If the man-o'-war's man did not recognize the word as a foreign name, he might very well mistake it for this much-used oath.

Comment: The man calling himself 'Goddedaal' was in fact Norris Carthew, an Englishman.